# MYSQL UNION - using a mysql string function?

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
(SELECT field1 FROM Table1) UNION
(SELECT field1 FROM Table2);
```

This gets all rows from both tables.
Is there a way to add the tablename into the results to make it easier to see where the record originated from? eg using an IF table1 then prepend a string to record?

An example record I currently get is

```
banana
```

I would like

```
t1-banana or t2-banana
```

Comment: We have **no idea** what your tables look like....

Comment: this will nullify one thing in the Union operator because then there will (probably) be all unique rows

Comment: If you need to know which table each row is from, why are you using `UNION` in the first place?

Comment: I have used a simple example above. Thanks for all the fast answers! I now know how to either create another column in the results or concat a string before existing results. Brilliant!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(SELECT CONCAT("t1-", field1) FROM Table1)
UNION
(SELECT CONCAT("t2-", field1) FROM Table2);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add the table name as the value of a second column:

```
(SELECT field1, 'Table1' AS table_name FROM Table1) 
UNION
(SELECT field1, 'Table2' AS table_name FROM Table2);
```

Comment: Yes. Rocket answered my question correctly but I have used this answer in my code as it is faster for me. Thanks

Comment: @Harry You should probably switch your answer then.

Answer (score 2):

```
(SELECT field1, 't1' as table_name FROM Table1)
UNION    
(SELECT field1, 't2' as table_name FROM Table2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(SELECT Concat(field1 , '-Table1') FROM Table1) UNION
(SELECT Concat(field1 , '-Table2') FROM Table2);
```

Comment: `+` works as a concatenation operator in SQL-Server, not MySQL.

Comment: To concat strings in MySQL, use `CONCAT`.